# How to provide X axis and Y Axis value in kendo chart crosshair tooltip?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart, kendo-tooltip

I am trying to get the X axis and Y axis value in crosshair tooltip of kendo chart. Please see: http://dojo.telerik.com/iDanE

How can this be done? How to specify the template for tooltip to contain both X axis and Y axis value? Want to have both category and value axis value in the same crosshair tooltip. Can this be done?

I just found a question with same requirement: http://www.telerik.com/forums/show-multiple-series-value-in-a-categoryaxis-crosshair-tooltip-

But how can use this in my example : http://dojo.telerik.com/iDanE    ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

According to their documentation, the crosshair tooltip template only has access to the axis value:  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-categoryAxis.crosshair.tooltip.template

So you could either add the second crosshair on the valueAxis:

**[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/oyAWu)**

or just show a regular tooltip with both category and value:

```
  tooltip: {
    visible: true,
    template: "#: category  # - #: value #"
  },
```

**[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/AHAgU)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Can the cross hair line made invisible? I just want the crosshair tooltip to be visible at the top?

Comment: @user2439903, yes either set the crosshair width to 0 or the opacity to 0.  http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/oqUHe